# Get Network Name (Subscriber Name) on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

How to get Network Name (Subscriber Name) on Windows Mobile?

Comment: like "Sprint" or "Verizon", etc, or something else?

Comment: Network Name = SIM Card provider company. Like Vodafone, Airtel etc

Answer (score 2):

In the namespace `Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status` in the assembly `Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status` in microsoft.windowsmobile.status.dll, you have the class `SystemState` with the perfectly matching property `PhoneOperatorName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RIL_GetOperatorList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917983.aspx) to retrieve the list of available operators. The array of  RILOPERATORINFO structures returned by this call will likely include one with a dwStatus of RIL_OPSTATUS_CURRENT which will be the name of the network operator you are currently connected to.

Be aware that the call to RIL_GetOperatorList can take quite a few seconds to complete since it is, in effect, searching for available networks.